# 'Local variable referenced before assignment' error, due to confusion with function name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting an unusual error, which I believe arises from using the same name for both a variable and a function. I didn't realise this could cause problems for Python. Can anyone shed some light?

**Code (inside Class definition):**

```
def post(self):
    username = self.request.get("username")
    password = self.request.get("password")
    verify = self.request.get("verify")
    email = self.request.get("email")
    error_username = error_username(username) # SOURCE OF ERROR
    error_password = error_password(password)
    error_verify = error_verify(password, verify)
    error_email = error_email(email)
    if all( [error_username == "", error_password == "",
        error_verify == "", error_email == ""] ):
        self.redirect("/unit2/welcome?username=%s" % escape_html(username))
    else:
        self.write_form(username, email, error_username,
                        error_password, error_verify, error_email)
```

**Error given:**

```
  File "/Users/max/python_projects/max-dev-udacity/signup.py", line 91, in post
    error_password = error_password(password)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'error_password' referenced before assignment
INFO     2014-07-22 18:03:12,466 module.py:640] default: "POST /unit2/signup HTTP/1.1" 500 228
```

error_username() is imported at the top of the sheet.

Note, when I change `error_username()` to some other function name, this error no longer occurs. Rather, the error occurs on the following line, presumably for the same reason.

Comment: Just to clarify - I realise this error gets raised a lot. It's just that I couldn't find anyone talking about this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same name for a function and a local name, no.

The scope of a name is determined at compile time based on binding behaviour; if you use a name as a function parameter, or as an import target, or you assign to it in a function, then it is a local name *throughout* the function.

As such, in the `post()` function, each of `error_username`, `error_password`, `error_verify` and `error_email` are local names; you have lines assigning values to each. You cannot use these names as globals first, then treat them as locals later.

Rename the local names, they are masking the functions.